# three dots in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for React app development. Whenever I make changes, three dots (an ellipsis) appear in the file and quickly shift the lines around. It is really annoying. How can I disable this behavior?
[image: Image of VS Code interface showing the issue.]

Comment: This looks like it is caused by an extension. What extensions have you got installed?

Comment: Yeah, I think it may be from git extension which I installed. I uninstalled all the extension, now its working fine. Thanks..:)

Comment: @HemaRamasamy Do you know what extension was causing this? I'm also facing this issue currently and it's driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

You can try deleting the GitLens or Git plugin.  I resolved my problem this way.

Comment: I can confirm that the GitLens plugin is (at least one possible) culprit for this behavior. I disabled it and the three dots and the jerking movement are gone.